# LookUp from two data extension at the same time?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, dataextensions, lookup-filter

We have couponcode email flow where we want to send out a reminder email to those who didn't use the code. 
We have several data extension with codes, because we have had to use new codes on a regular basis. 
The issue is that the list of customers we want to sent to has codes from different data extensions. So my question is - is it possible to do a LookUp in 2 different data extensions, somewhat like this:

```
%%[
VAR @CouponCode
SET @CouponCode = Lookup("FLIPP-DK2016_new", "CouponCode", "Contact_Key", _SubscriberKey)
SET @CouponCode = Lookup("FLIPP-DK2017", "CouponCode", "Contact_Key", _SubscriberKey)
]%%
```

I am aware that this is not the way to do it, because it is not working for me. Any suggestion to how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

I'd check to make sure the first one returns nothing before checking the next:

```
%%[

VAR @CouponCode
SET @CouponCode = Lookup("FLIPP-DK2016_new", "CouponCode", "Contact_Key", _SubscriberKey)

if empty(@couponCode) then
    SET @CouponCode = Lookup("FLIPP-DK2017", "CouponCode", "Contact_Key", _SubscriberKey)
endif

]%%
```